# How to adjust the height of the Mahapps window to minimum height

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I would like to adjust the height of the Mahapps window to very minimum (say just 5) with ShowTitlebar=false.  If I try to resize the window by dragging the corner, I can resize only upto about 36 (which is titlebar height).

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TestWPF.MahappsWindow1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="MahappsWindow1" Height="300" Width="300"
    UseNoneWindowStyle="True" MinHeight="1" MinWidth="1" ShowTitleBar="False">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

I can resize upto with the below snap shot height:
[Mahapps Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZt5x.png)

However, the window height can be adjusted in Windows and ModernUI when the WindowStyle is set to none.

The below modern ui code can resize to minimum height of 1.

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="TestWPF.ModernWindow1"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
               xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
              xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
              xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
              mc:Ignorable="d"  
              Height="400" Width="400" WindowStyle="None"
              MinHeight="1" MinWidth="100" IsTitleVisible="False" 
              Title="ModernWindow" ResizeMode="CanResize"   
               xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
              LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z" Loaded="ModernWindow_Loaded"
            >

<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I can resize upto with the below snap shot height of 1:
[Modern UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrn7K.png)

Is there way I can reduce the size of Mahapps window to minumum height of less than 36 without titlebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Mahapps.  It is not possible to resize the mahapps window beyond titlebar height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide grid in % manner than use binding:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=YourElementName, Mode=OneWay}"
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=YourElementName, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  I would like to know how far mahapps allows resize its window.  Modern and default window allows resize upto 5px while mahaps stops the resize at about 36 px. I can't resize below 36px height.